# C structs and linked lists struggle

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list

So, we just started learning linked lists and data structures in my online class, but I have been really struggling with this topic. I have a general understanding of pointers but when you combine everything, I get completely lost.

So for this program, I am supposed to process employee data and access it through the use of structs and pointers. However, I think I am not passing the correct values into the functions because the data is not being saved and I can't access it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct address {
    char street[49];
    char city[29];
    char state[2];
    char zip[5];
};

struct data{
    char name[39];
    struct address addy;
    float salary;
    struct data *next;
} emp;

void LIST(struct data* head);
void INSERT(struct data* head, char* name, struct address addr, float salary);
void DELETE(char* name, struct data* head);
void EDIT(struct data* head, char* name, struct address addr, float salary);
void CALCPAYROLL(struct data* head);
void HELP();

int main()
{
    char input[15];
    int quitter = 1;
    struct data *head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(emp));
    if (head == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    while(quitter == 1)
    {
        printf(" enter command:  \n");
        fgets(input,15, stdin);
        input[strlen(input) -1] = '\0';
        if((strcmp(input, "List") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "list") == 0))
        {
            LIST(head);
        }
        if((strcmp(input, "Insert") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "insert") == 0))
        {
            scanf("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%f", head->name, head->addy.street, head->addy.city, head->addy.state, head->addy.zip, &head->salary);
            INSERT(head, head->name, head->addy, head->salary);
        }
        if ((strcmp(input, "Delete") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "delete") == 0))
        {
            DELETE(head->name, head);
        }
        if ((strcmp(input, "Edit") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "edit") == 0))
        {
            EDIT(head, head->name, head->addy, head->salary);
        }
        if ((strcmp(input, "Payroll") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "payroll") == 0))
        {
            CALCPAYROLL(head);
        }
        if ((strcmp(input, "Help") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "help") == 0))
        {
            HELP();
        }
        if ((strcmp(input, "Quit") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "quit") == 0))
        {
            printf("============\nGood bye!\n");
            quitter = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void LIST(struct data* head)
{
    struct data* temp = head;
    while (temp) {
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s, %2s %5s\n%9.2f\n-----\n", temp->name, temp->addy.street, temp->addy.city, temp->addy.state, temp->addy.zip, temp->salary);
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s, %2s %5s\n%9.2f\n-----\n", temp->name, temp->addy.street, temp->addy.city, temp->addy.state, temp->addy.zip, temp->salary);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void INSERT(struct data* head, char* name, struct address addr, float salary)
{
    struct data* newEmployee = NULL;
    newEmployee = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(emp));

    strcpy(newEmployee->name, head->name);
    newEmployee->salary = head->salary;

    strcpy(newEmployee->addy.street, head->addy.street);

    strcpy(newEmployee->addy.city, head->addy.city);

    strcpy(newEmployee->addy.state, head->addy.state);

    strcpy(newEmployee->addy.zip, head->addy.zip);
    struct data* temp = head;
    while(temp->next && temp->next->name > newEmployee->name) 
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newEmployee->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newEmployee;

}

void DELETE(char* name, struct data* head)
{
    char del[39];
    scanf("%39s", del);
    struct data * toBeDeleted = NULL;
    struct data * temp = head;
    while (strcmp(del, temp->name) == 0) 
        {
           strcpy(temp->next->name, temp->name);

           temp->addy = temp->next->addy;
           temp->salary = temp->next->salary;
           toBeDeleted = temp->next;
           temp->next = temp->next->next;
           free(toBeDeleted);
           printf("RECORD DELETED\n");
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("RECORD NOT FOUND\n");
}

void EDIT(struct data* head, char* name, struct address addr, float salary)
{
    char edit[39];
    scanf("%39s", edit);
    struct data* temp = head;
    while (strcmp(edit, temp->name) == 0) 
        {
            temp->addy = addr;
            temp->salary = salary;

            printf("RECORD EDITED\n");
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    printf("RECORD NOT FOUND\n");
}

void CALCPAYROLL(struct data* head)
{
    struct data* temp = head;
    float total;
    while (temp) 
    {
        total += temp->salary;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("total payroll: %f", total);
}

void HELP()
{
    printf("commands:\n");
    printf("List - shows the list of employees\n");
    printf("Insert - Creates a new employee record\n");
    printf("Delete - Deletes an existing employee record\n");
    printf("Edit - Modifies the contents of an employee record\n");
    printf("Payroll - Calculates and displays the total payroll\n");
    printf("Help - Displays the set of available commands\n");
    printf("Quit - Prints the message ""good bye!"" and exits the program" );
}
```

Comment: Secondary issue: in your INSERT function you are trying to compare two strings using the `>` operator.  Probably you want something like `strcmp(name1, name2)` instead, with the sign of the result determining which is alphabetically first.

Comment: using all CAPS for function names makes the code much more difficult to understand.  All CAPS is (by convention) only used for macro names, const names.   In C, that means that `#define ALL_CAPS_NAME 1`  is expected, but not function names.  For function names suggest either `lowerCamelCase()` or `snake_name()`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' number are numbers with no basis. I.E. 2, 5, 15, 29, 39, 49.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: in general, it is best when performing a `==` comparison to place the literal on the left, then some keypunch error like using `=` rather than `==` will be caught by the compiler rather than you getting gray hairs and lots of frustration trying to debug the problem

Comment: the returned value from a call to `fgets()` should be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this statement: `if((strcmp(input, "List") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "list") == 0))
        {`  will not catch when the user enters a mixed case input.  And how is the user to know what the valid commands are?  the code should be displaying a menu, then ask for the input.  With a menu the commands could be reduced to single character, then the checking would be via: `switch( tolower(input) ) { case ..... }

Comment: for the 'INSERT()' values, the posted code is using a format string in a call to `scanf()` that has embedded '-' but nothing is telling the user that is how to format the input

Comment: this line: `newEmployee = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(emp))` has a few problems.  1) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) when  calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there is a major oops in the code.  The pointer `head` is being used to point to the first entry in the linked list AND being used for the receiving area from the call to `scanf()`  This will not work as implemented.

Comment: in function: `INSERT()`, the line: `temp = temp->next;` will not work for the first entry because the field in `head.next` has not been initialized to NULL.

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, with the input format specifier: '%s', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid overflow.  As written, the call to `scanf()` will input all the user input into the first field which will cause a buffer overflow.  Such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate all code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 3) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: your compiler should have output about 1/2 dozen warning messages. You should fix those problems.  Note: when a prototype is written for a function that takes no parameters, place `void` between the parens

Comment: appropriate horizontal spacing, for instance inside parens and after comma and semicolons makes the code much easier to read.  The compiler doesn't care, but us humans do.

Comment: the code contains a lot of unused parameters, for instance in function: `INSERT()`, the parameter: `struct address addr`  (which should have been passed as a pointer) is not used, so should be removed.  Similar considerations exist for the `float salary` parameter

Comment: in function: `DELETE()`, the parameter: `char *name` is not used.   The lines: `char del[39];
    scanf("%39s", del);` is not correct, the MAX characters modifier must be one less than the length of the `del[]` buffer, because of the name was 39 characters long the `scanf()` would still append a NUL byte, resulting in a buffer overflow I.E. undefined behavior, which can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: in the function: `DELETE()`, this line: `while (strcmp(del, temp->name) == 0)` will cause the delete operation to fail (unless the very first entry, in `head` matches, but that is not part of the linked list entries. and you really do not want to delete/free `head`  Suggest: `while( temp->next != NULL )`

Comment: this logic: `printf("RECORD DELETED\n");
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        printf("RECORD NOT FOUND\n");` is not correct as it can output both messages

Comment: regarding: `printf("total payroll: %f", total);`  in almost all cases, when calling `printf()`, the format string should end with '\n', so the message is immediately passed through to the terminal

Comment: in function: `INSERT()`, the field `newEmployee->next` is not being initialized to NULL, so the `while()` statement will (probably) never find an instance where `temp->next` is NULL.   This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `newEmployee->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = newEmployee;`   this eliminates all from the linked list (which results, amongst other things, in a memory leak) except the `head->next` and the `newEmployee`.

Comment: in function: `DELETE()`, the `while()` loop, if ever entered, (or corrected) will not stop when it encounters a `temp->next` field that contains NULL

Comment: in the `EDIT()` function (and others) this line: `temp = temp->next;` is outside the `while()` loop, and will modify the contents of the node pointed to by `head` and no other.  However, that is the container for the input fields, so the code will be copying the data over itself.

Comment: in function: `CALCPAYROLL()`,  the variable `float total;` is not initialized, so this line: `total += temp->salary;` will be adding to some random value rather than starting at `0.0f`   This line: `struct data* temp = head;` should be accessing the first node, not the input fields, so it should be: `struct data* temp = head->next;`   There are other instances of this same error elsewhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have to commend you for a very neat presentation.  The code is readable and easy to follow.  The only fault I find with it is that all uppercase names are usually reserved for macros and constants declared with `#define`.

Here:

```
struct data{
    char name[39];
    struct address addy;
    float salary;
    struct data *next;
} emp;                  // declaring a variable at the same time as the structure? Not very nice.
```

I see an issue that happens when you create your first list item, the head.  Insert must have a way to modify the `head` parameter.  This needs an extra  level of indirection.  INSERT should also return an error code, in case malloc fails, a common way to do this is to return a negative value (-1) on error.

```
void INSERT(struct data* head, char* name, struct address addr, float salary)

// should be 
int INSERT(struct data** head, char* name, struct address addr, float salary)
```

You'll have to change the logic a little bit to set `head` with the newly allocated buffer when `head` is NULL on entry.  Calling INSERT then becomes.

```
   if (INSERT(&head, name, &addr, salary) < 0)
   {
      // error !
   }
```

I see a problem in data allocation in INSERT.

```
struct data* newEmployee = NULL;
//newEmployee = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(emp)); // ?? you allocate a struct data, what's emp?
// should read
newEmployee = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

DELETE and EDIT do not work. They cannot find the employee as written. You should consider using a find() function, something like this:

```
data* FindEmployeeData(data* head, const char* name)
{
   while (head)
   {
      if (strcmp(head->name, name) == 0)
        break;
      head = head->next;
   }
   return head;
}
```

This could be a time saver when writing new operations on employees.

In INSERT:

```
while(temp->next && temp->next->name > newEmployee->name)
```

I thought strings were supposed to be compared with `strcmp()`...

In DELETE: same as for INSERT, the function could change the head of the list

```
int DELETE(data** head, const char* name); // returns -1 on error.
```

Here:

```
scanf("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%f", head->name, head->addy.street, head->addy.city, head->addy.state, head->addy.zip, &head->salary);
```

Terrible things **will** happen when the user enters a name, address, state, street, city or zip that are too long for the space you have allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm applying everything right now!

Comment: this answer is not quite correct because the code is only using the `->next` field in the linked list and using where `head` points as input fields, filled by the user.  So the contents of the `head` pointer are not changed.

Comment: ?? 'head' changes at statement `head = head->next;`. `head` is used as the pointer to walk the list.  There is no change needed to the list itself, this is just a read-only find().

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the data because in INSERT function head must be a *double pointer*, because when you want to insert something in the head of a linked list you have to change the address stored in head. In your code you're modifying a *copy* of head. remember that in C *everything is passed  for value*. This mean that for modify the address content in a pointer you have to pass *the address of the pointer* at your function.

Comment: insert adds the new employee at the end of the list.

Comment: No. He's making an ordered list, there's a while that he use for searching where to put the new element. However, also if want to append all the element at the end of the list he has to modify head's content the first time, so my explanation is still valid.

Comment: As an alternative to using a double pointer, INSERT could return a pointer to the first node (return the head of the linked list).

Comment: That doesn't work.  If malloc fails in INSERT, the caller could lose the entire list

Comment: So, in your solution where you talk about while(temp->next && name > newEmployee->name) {temp = temp->next;} he is not finding where to insert the element. This is terrible...... (Of course he has to change the ">" with strcmp() in the while)